# OpenCL: Intel -Generating Intermediate Program Binaries with Offline Compiler

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencl, intel

I am using Intel opencl SDK on Windows with Intel HD graphics. Would like to compile my kernel offline then use in host code:

```
clCreateProgramFromBinary(…)
```

This [link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/515213) says :

```
OpenCL™ API Offline Compiler plug-in for Microsoft Visual Studio* IDE enables you to develop OpenCL applications with Visual Studio IDE.

The plug-in supports the following features:

New project templates
New OpenCL file (*.cl) template
Syntax highlighting
Types and functions auto-completion
Offline compilation and build of OpenCL kernels
LLVM code view
Assembly code view
program IR generation
Selection of target OpenCL device – CPU or Intel Graphics

NOTE

To work with the plug-in features, create an OpenCL project template \or convert an existing project into the OpenCL project.
```

I want to use this feature, so I wanted to know what all I have to install?

As per the note above   I should create an OpenCL project template. How do I do this? Also what do we mean by  "or convert an existing project into the OpenCL project"

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the feature you just need to have the SDK installed on your system.

To create a new Empty OpenCL project template:

1. Go to: **File** > **New** > **Project...**
2. Look for **OpenCL** group under **Templates\Visual C++** section and select **Empty OpenCL Project for Windows**
3. Once project created you can add a new OpenCL Code File (**Project** > **Add New Item...** > **OpenCL** > **Intel SDK for OpenCL Application File**) or add an exisitin *.cl file to the project
4. Configure the project's options to generate binary file (instructions [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/515221)): **Project** > **Properties** > **Intel SDK for OpenCL Applications** > **General** > **Generate binary file**
5. Whenever you build the project, the OpenCL compiler will build all attached .cl files and generate for them program binaries.

To convert an existing Visual Studio project (instructions [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/515215)), do the following:

1. Right-click on the project you want to convert in the Solution Explorer.
2. In the project menu click **Convert to a project for OpenCL API**